# How to I solve this Issue with fgets in C?

Tags: c, fgets

I am very new at coding so bare with me. I was using fgets for an assignment which included asking questions to the viewer. Every time I had a line with fgets, it would jump directly to the next question without letting the viewer answer the first question asked. (I'm using Repl.it btw)

Code section that's not working:

```
printf("What's your eye colour?");
scanf("%s", colour);

printf("What country do you want to visit?");
fgets(country, 20, stdin);

printf("How many pets do you have?");
scanf("%d", &pets);
```

Result:

```
What's your eye colour? Blue
What country do you want to visit?How many pets do you have?
```

I have to use fgets, not scanf because the answer needs to have a blank space. Thank you to anyone that can help out!

Comment: If it were me, I'd probably use `fgets()` for all the input. But note that `fgets()` retains the `'\n'` at the end of the string, so you might want to [remove that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/100770).

Comment: What do you mean by retains \n? how do I remove it? Thanks!

Comment: And FWIW, I think the [top voted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462221/10077) is better than the accepted answer.

Comment: I mean, if the user types "Italy" and hits the enter key, the resulting string in `country` will be `"Italy\n"`. That's likely to screw up any output you attempt with this. To remove it, see the link in my previous comment.

Comment: The issue isn't after the user types a country, It asks both those questions at once, without allowing the viewer to answer the first one.

Comment: Not if you use `fgets()` instead of `scanf()` for the first question. See the duplicate. The `scanf()` is leaving the `'\n'` in the stream, so that's all you get for the answer to your second question.

Comment: Oh, that worked. thank you!