# If statement, wont let me take input and it works without if (in C)

Tags: c, if-statement, scanf, c-strings, fgets

I am trying to make a program that prompts you to choose 1 or 2. 1 being to make a file and 2 being to append a file. Whenever I run the code for if (opt == 1) with the if it skips the prompt that asks about what the file name will be. I hope I'm being clear and you can understand my problem.

EXPECTED OUTPUT-

Enter a file name: (input)

Enter file contents: (input)

ACTUAL OUTPUT-

Enter a file name: Enter file contents: (input)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    char fname[20];
    char fcontents[250];
    int opt;

    printf("Make a file(1),Append a file(2)");
    scanf("%d", &opt);

    if (opt == 1)
    {
        printf("Enter a file name: ");
        fgets(fname, 20, stdin);
        printf("Enter file contents: ");
        fgets(fcontents, 250, stdin);
        FILE* fpointer = fopen(fname, "w");
        fprintf(fpointer, "%s", fcontents);
        fclose(fpointer);
        printf("FILE: %s successfully created", fname);
    }
    else if (opt == 2) 
    {
        printf("Enter a file name: ");
        fgets(fname, 20, stdin);
        printf("Enter file appends: ");
        fgets(fcontents, 250, stdin);
        FILE* fpointer = fopen(fname, "a");
        fprintf(fpointer, "%s", fcontents);
        fclose(fpointer);
        printf("FILE: %s successfully created", fname);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `scanf` function leaves the newline from your `Enter` key in the input buffer for the `fgets` call to read as an empty line. Don't mix `scanf` and `fgets`. In fact, `scanf` can cause more problems than it solves, use `fgets` to read the whole line, then use `sscanf` to parse the input.

Comment: Could you explain more about what I have to do? I'm kind of new to C and don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [scanf() leaves the newline character in the buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240789/scanf-leaves-the-newline-character-in-the-buffer)

Comment: One debugger breakpoint and a single-step, and/or one well-placed `printf` of `fname` would expose where the problem is. The link provided by Gerhardh will tell you what is going on, and ways to fix it, though I think [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64880882/how-to-i-solve-this-issue-with-fgets-in-c) (also marked a duplicate) is more tightly related. This problem is posted by those new to C a dozen times a week, it seems.

Comment: You could call `scanf(" ");` between the `printf()` in the `if` section and the first `fgets()` to eat any white-space that was left behind by `scanf("%d", &opt);` in the input (i.e. the newline character). (You would also need to do the same in the `else if` section.)

Answer (score 1):

After this call of `scanf`

```
scanf("%d", &opt);
```

the input buffer contains the new line character `'\n'` that corresponds to the pressed key Enter.

So the next call of `fgets` reads an empty string that contains this new line character.

A simple way to resolve the problem is to use the function `scanf` instead of `fgets` as for example

```
scanf( " %19[^\n]", fname );
```

If the file name can not contain spaces then it will be even simpler to write

```
scanf( "%19s", fname );
```

To read the content stored in the file it is better to write

```
scanf( " %249[^\n], fcontents );
```

Pay attention to the leading space in the format string. It allows to skip white space characters.

Another approach is to use everywhere the function `fgets`.

To get a value for the variable `opt` you can use in this case functions `atoi` or `strtol` that convert strings to integers.

Bear in mind that the function `fgets` also can append the read string with the new line character that you should remove at least in the variable `fname`. To do that you need to include header `<string.h>` and write for example

```
fgets( fname, sizeof( fname ), stdin );
fname[ strcspn( fname, "\n" ) ] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `getchar()` after the `scanf()` function.

```
int opt;

printf("Make a file(1),Append a file(2)");

scanf("%d", &opt);
getchar();
```